# Differences between .SendKeys(Keys.Enter) and .Click()?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with some automation scripts using `C#` and `Selenium`, running my tests on `IE11`. I was trying to click on a link using the `.Click()` function from WebElement and it wasn't working at all so I tried to use the `.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` function and it worked.

I'm trying to understand this behavior but I can't figure out why is this happening.

Does anyone know the difference between using `.Click()` and `.SendKeys(Keys.Enter)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html)

`Click()`

> ...If this causes a new page to load, this method will attempt to block until the page has loaded. At this point, you should discard all references to this element and any further operations performed on this element will throw a StaleElementReferenceException...
>
> ...There are some preconditions for an element to be clicked. The element must be visible and it must have a height and width greater then 0.

`SendKeys()`

> Use this method to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.

Both simulate user action on the web element. But while `SendKeys()` tries to perform the action without consideration to anything else `Click()` has some safe guards, like "stopping" the code from continue until page load event is received. Also, the method won't try to execute without meeting some preconditions to avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Calling .SendKeys(Keys.Enter) is not a realistic way to write your test cases, as a human user wouldn't be able to do so in most cases, and even if he is, he would usually prefer to click.

Thus, you should try to alter your locators for .Click() to work. MSIE is a little picky sometimes when it comes to clickable elements. For instance, I had an HTML snippet like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="executeSomeJavaScript()">
    <span>
        <span>Abmelden</span>
    </span>
</button>
```

When I tried to call

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='Abmelden']").Click();
```

it didn't work in MSIE. After altering the locator to

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='Abmelden']/ancestor::button").Click();
```

everything was fine, as the button is the clickable element, not the span.

In other browsers, this usually doesn't matter, as they simply generate the click into the X and Y coordinates where the element's bounds rect has its horizontal and vertical center.